# Remove background from selected dates | flatpickr.js

Tags: css, flatpickr

How can I remove [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0gCG.png) background from inRange items?

```css
.flatpickr-day.startRange,.flatpickr-day.endRange {
    background: #353535;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.flatpickr-day.inRange {
    background: #353535;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
.flatpickr-day.inRange {
    background: #353535;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
 }
```